# Inset a new field in an array of sub-document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following schema:

```
{
   "name"    : "MyName",
   "actions" : [{
       "kind"   : "kind1",
       "result" : "result1"
   },
   {
       "kind":"kind1",
       "result":"result1"
   }
   ]
}
```

I want to insert a new field called 'expected' in different subdocument in actions. I tried the following command but I have an issue with it:

```
db.tasks.update({},{$push:{ "actions.expected" : "MyExpected" }},false,true)
can't append to array using string field name expected
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $addToSet functionality:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Try

```
db.tasks.update({}, {$addToSet: {'actions.expected': 'MyExpected'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have json object inside array but in the query you are trying to add string. Thats why you got an exception. You can update your query as follows.

```
db.tasks.update({},{$push:{ "actions" : {"expected" : "MyExpected"} }},false,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you're trying to `$push` into an array, but the destination you're giving is not an array.

`actions.expected` is the `expected` field in the `actions` field, and you're pushing `"MyExpected"` into that array - but such an array does not exist.

Let's *assume* you had the following data, perhaps that explains it best. Your query would work on a data structure like this:

```
actions : { expected : [] } // actions is an object here
// ... {$push:{ "actions.expected" : "MyExpected" }}
actions : { expected : ["MyExpected"] }
```

Instead, you'll probably want to push an object into the actions array:

```
actions : []
$push : { "actions" : { "expected" : "MyExpected" } }
actions : [ { "expected" : "MyExpected" } ]
```